# Switching to Xcode 10 causes `UserNotifications.framekwor dyld: Library not loaded crash` for iOS9

Tags: ios, iphone, dependencies, xcode10, usernotifications

We have an app that is working properly with the `UserNotification.framework` being linked as `required` framework in Xcode 9. Everything works smooth here.

Now we are switching to Xcode 10. But there linking this framework as `required` leads to

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/UserNotifications.framework/UserNotifications
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/1D41BD68-9B88-4D5D-B7AB-0D1C31979964/App.app/App
  Reason: image not found
```

If I switch it to `optional` push notification (via Intercom) won't work anymore.

What is the reason? How can we fix that? Why is it even working in Xcode 9?

#### Update #1

using

```
@import UserNotification
```

does not fix it

#### Update #2

Its fixed by importing and using it actually (in `AppDelegate.m`) like this

```
UNNotificationRequest* unr = [UNNotificationRequest alloc];
unr = nil;
```

*Why?*

It is related to the same issue I have experienced already.

[CABTMidiCentralViewController used in Storyboard only working if using code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53242852/cabtmidicentralviewcontroller-used-in-storyboard-only-working-if-using-code-refe)

#### Update #3

More generic question

[Xcode sometimes removes linked library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349985/xcode-sometimes-removes-linked-library)

Comment: What is your Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries value in Build settings? Did you try to clear derived data and build folder?

Comment: It's saying `yes`. Yes i have tried that. (Same happening from builds from our Nevercode CI, and thats a blank sandbox always, so its not an caching issue)

Comment: Why do you even link the framework manually? `CLANG_MODULES_AUTOLINK` (Link Frameworks Automatically) should be enabled by default, and you just `import` the framework and check for availability in your code (you'll also get fixit prompts for older os versions)

Comment: @Alladinian Its set to `yes` but somehow the compiler seems to optimize the code and removes some frameworks that are not explicitly mentioned in my code. See the updated answer

Comment: You must link this framework as `optional` if your Deployment Target is below iOS 10.

Answer (score 0):

UserNotification SDK is available on iOS 10+, Try to update the deployment Target to iOS 10 +

Comment: Thats not an option

Answer (score -2):

Can your please try removing the framework and adding that again ? I just created a new project this framework added in Xcode 10 and was able to run in the device without any errors.

Comment: Did you use an ios9 device?