# Xcode sometimes removes linked library

Tags: xcode, linker, dependencies, ios-frameworks, dyld

When using different `Frameworks` in Xcode, the compiler and linker sometimes do not include that `Framework` in the library. The result is an immediate crash during the startup with the following message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/UserNotifications.framework/UserNotifications
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/1D41BD68-9B88-4D5D-B7AB-0D1C31979964/App.app/App
  Reason: image not found
```

I found one way to avoid this. Its just mentioning the parts of that library within the apps code directly like this:

```
UNNotificationRequest *unr = [UNNotificationRequest alloc];
```

Just including a file from that framework with `#include <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>` does not fix it. Nor does `@import UserNotifications;`

I have seen it with different libraries on different xcode versions for different ios versions.

Here are two other issues that have a more specific use case:

1) [CABTMidiCentralViewController used in Storyboard only working if using code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53242852/cabtmidicentralviewcontroller-used-in-storyboard-only-working-if-using-code-refe)

2) [Switching to Xcode 10 causes `UserNotifications.framekwor dyld: Library not loaded crash` for iOS9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54344463/switching-to-xcode-10-causes-usernotifications-framekwor-dyld-library-not-load)

**Does anybody know why this is happening? And how to avoid that dumb part of code but still link / embed the desired framework?**

#### P.S.

1. I have set `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` to `YES`
2. I have set `Link Frameworks Automatically` to `YES`

### Update #1

The issue with the `UserNotifications` framework:

#### iOS9 & XCode 9 - WORKS

[image: No crash on iOS9 with XCode9]

#### iOS9 with XCode 10 - CRASH

[image: Crash on iOS9 with XCode10]

Using the simulator:

[image: iOS9 & XCode 10 Crashh - simulator]

Using a real device:

[image]

### Update #2

It is not crashing when I change the framework from `Required` to `Optional` but then the push notifications are not working.

Comment: My suggestion: share the complete crash log from the crash, and information about the iOS versions you're seeing the crash on. The two build settings you mention are unrelated to any runtime crash about failing to find a system framework.

Comment: What is your iOS development target? Is the framework added in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" or in "Embedded Binaries" (in the "General" tab)? What about the "Build Phases" tab? Do you have it in "Link Binary with Libraries"? In "Embed Frameworks"?

Comment: You mean Deployment Target?: `9.3`
Yes, its in both areas of `Linked F and L`
No, its not in Embedded as it then shows up like `UserNotification.framework ...in ../../../../../Applications/XCode.app.....` which is not an option for our CI and team work

Answer (score 0):

UserNotifications.framework is a system framework, and to be used it must exist on the system your application is running on. It was added relatively recently, so my guess is you're seeing the error about it being missing when running on older iOS versions that predate the framework's existence.

Comment: Well, its happening with different frameworks with the absolut same behavior and fixes

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. If you're running on iOS < 10.0, UserNotification.framework doesn't exist and so your app will crash on launch with this message. Are you seeing this crash on an iOS version older than 10.0, or newer?

Comment: The crash happens on ios9 build with xcode10 but is working on ios9 when built with xcode9.

Comment: There’s something you’re not sharing. UserNotification.framework doesn’t exist on iOS 9, so there’s no way an app linking against it and using it works on iOS 9. Now, there are alternative techniques that can allow it to work (weak linking the framework and falling back to an alternate API, for instance), but you haven’t mentioned doing anything like this.

Comment: What do you mean by _not sharing_? The UserNotifications somehow exists on iOS9, why is the build not crashing on iOS9 when built with XCode9 **and** the Push Notifications are working? The very same project in XCode10 (with legacy build system enabled) will lead to a crash on iOS9 (with option set to `requred`) or not crash, but simply no push notifications will work (with option set to `optional`.

By the way, i have updated the question

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications - the documentation clearly states the framework is only available on iOS 10+. If you’re expecting it to work on older iOS versions, you’re in unsupported territory. I don’t know how to say that any more clearly.